# Eclipse Intellisense operation

Tags: java, eclipse

As I'm typing the code, does eclipse look up instantly in the class file in order to retrieve the class members for the intellisense or is there a file seperately created that eclipse refers to?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about how Eclipse JDT content assist works.  When you press `.`, a content assist invocation occurs.  This triggers a *reconcile* operation in JDT.  A reconcile is kind of like a mini-compile.  The current file is parsed and resolved, but no byte code is created (that's what a reconcile is).  The results of the reconcile are what is used to populate content assist.

This is only scratching the surface of what is going on.  In actuality, things are quite complex with caches, diet parses, and bindings used and created as needed.